# How to implement IsDirty on properties that are collections in MVVM pattern with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

How to implement IsDirty mechanism on properties that are collections in MVVM pattern with WPF?

IsDirty is a flag that indicates if the data in the viewmodel has changed and it is used for the save operation.

How to propagate IsDirty ?

Comment: I strongly suggest you read [this article](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `IsDirty` is just treated as another property on the `ViewModel`; when it comes time to save, check if the object is dirty and do the necessary work. What exactly are you trying to propagate?

Comment: I prefer version counters over dirty flags. Increment the counter on any change. Store the counter of the last save operation. Compute `IsDirty` by comparing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom collection along these lines...

```
 public class MyCollection<T>:ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        // implementation goes here...
        //
        private bool _isDirty;
        public bool IsDirty
        {
            [DebuggerStepThrough]
            get { return _isDirty; }
            [DebuggerStepThrough]
            set
            {
                if (value != _isDirty)
                {
                    _isDirty = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty");
                }
            }
        }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

And declare your collections like this...

```
MyCollection<string> SomeStrings = new MyCollection<string>();
SomeStrings.Add("hello world");
SomeStrings.IsDirty = true;
```

This approach lets you enjoy the benefits of ObservableCollection and simultaneously allows you to append a property of interest.  If your Vm's do not use ObservableCollection, you can inherit from List of T using the same pattern.